# setProduct hook isnt a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, downshift

I keep getting an error saying that the setProduct value isn't a function in my react code. Here is a codesandbox example of what I've been working on.

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-jang-0ro1v

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: while this question could better pinpoint the line of code, I would consider a codesandbox a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recommend typescript enough. The return value of `useState` is  an array type. You need to unpack it using array syntax: `const [product, setProduct] = useState()`